# How to tell the date of a YouTube comment?

Tags: youtube

There was this issue on YouTube, that if a video was posted on Feb 24, 2021, and today is Feb 16, 2023, then YouTube would say it is "1 year ago", although most people without any AI would say it is 2 years.

So that's solvable because we can hover the mouse over that "1 year ago" and still see it is more accurately 2 years:

[image]

However, the issue arises, when it is a video that talks about a stock or Bitcoin.  The comment may say it is "1 year ago", but we really don't know if it is "1 year and 1 day ago", or "1 year and 360 days ago", and hovering the mouse on it has no effect:

(here it is 2 years, and that means it can be "2 years and 1 day" or "2 years and 360 days" ago):

[image]

I want to know if what the commenter says make sense or when did he say that, and obviously whether he said it on March 1, 2021 or Dec 28, 2021 make a difference.

So is there a way to tell the date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Hadzy](https://hadzy.com/analytics/youtube/) tool - just enter the video link, search for the comment and it should tell you more info, including the comment date and time.